# Cannot create sql  server database user correctly

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a user in a SQL Server database with SQL authentication. That's what I did:

1. Created database named `testDb` (with default parameters)
2. ran script

   ```
   CREATE LOGIN test 
       WITH PASSWORD = 'test';
   USE testDb;
   CREATE USER test FOR LOGIN test;
   GO
   ```
3. Ensured user `test` appeared in `Databases\testDb\Security` (in Management Studio)
4. Tried to connect to the server with Management Studio using user `test`
5. Got 18456 error.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition. The OS is Windows 7 Ultimate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything that you're doing wrong - this *should* work just fine (and did on my machine just now)..... did you mistype the password by any chance?? .....

Comment: no way. I tried many times (even in notepad). Might anything be wrong with server settings?

Comment: Have you configured the instance to allow mixed mode authentication and then restarted it? By default SQL Server logins are disabled.

Comment: No, I set up with default settings. It there a way to change it now? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default SQL Server logins are disabled.

You need to right click the instance in SSMS object Explorer then from the "Properties" dialogue, Security Tab enable "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

This requires a restart of the SQL Server service to take effect,